# How to rotate door on y-axis, triggered by the player

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, first-person-shooter

I am trying to create the door that is triggered by the player in an FPS game.

I can't figure out how to make the door rotate only on y-axis. I want the door to be triggered by the player, but still stay on the y axis at the same time. Instead my code is making the door rotate on all angles towards the target.

````
public class DoorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Door;
    public GameObject player;
    public bool isOpen;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    private Transform target;
    private Quaternion lookRotation;
    private Vector3 direction;
    //public float moveSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (isOpen)
        {
            target = player.transform;
            direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
            lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        isOpen = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        isOpen = false;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

As shown in gobs of past Q&A here (remember to search before posting):

```
target = player.transform;

//No benefit from normalizing this.
direction = target.position - transform.position;

// Flatten this into the horizontal plane.
direction.y = 0;

lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

// No benefit from Slerp here — use cheaper Lerp.
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

// Or, if you want constant rotation speed, use RotateTwoards.
```